# NHibernate query is not returning any results

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to get Fluent and NHibernate configured properly with ASP.NET MVC. As far as I know it's configured properly but when I access the page that uses this setup I am not receiving any data results.

The model I'm using is called `Brand` and the database table is `Brands`.

Here is a snippet from my BrandController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IRepository<Brand> repo = new BrandRepository();
    var brands = repo.GetAll().ToList<Brand>();

     return View(brands);
}
```

Here is a snippet from my BrandRepository:

```
ICollection<Brand> IRepository<Brand>.GetAll()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        var brands = session
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(Brand))
            .List<Brand>();

        return brands;
    }
}
```

Here is my NHibernateHelper:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(
                        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                            .ConnectionString(c => c
                                .FromConnectionStringWithKey("ShoesFullAccess")
                            )
                    )
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Here is my Brand model:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Style> Styles { get; private set; }

    public Brand()
    {
        Styles = new List<Style>();
    }

    public virtual void AddStyle(Style style)
    {
        Styles.Add(style);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my BrandMap:

```
public class BrandMap : ClassMap<Brand>
{
    public BrandMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Styles)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction for how I can narrow down the problem I would very grateful!

Comment: Just to be sure, the database, table, data exist right?

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not adding the mappings to the configuration.

Add this before `.BuildSessionFactory()`:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BrandMap>())
```

Comment: You're right. I did have to make this modification! I also had to make a few others.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make a few modifications to my code. The first and main one was adding the mappings to the configuration as Diego pointed out.

> You are not adding the mappings to the configuration.
>
> Add this before .BuildSessionFactory():
>
> `.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BrandMap>())`

The next thing I had to fix was my `Brand` model. I needed to make the `Id` field `virtual`.

And finally, I needed to change my `BrandMap` just a little bit -- I had to specify exactly which table it was pointing to by adding this code `Table("Brands");`